# Boot server from pxe

Tags: linux, boot, pxe

I need to connect to a server via idrac and boot it from PXE
 I tried:

```
racadm config -g cfgServerInfo -o cfgServerFirstBootDevice PXE
```

I get the following error:

> RAC1169: The RACADM "config" command will be deprecated in a future version of iDRAC firmware. Run the RACADM "racadm set" command to configure the iDRAC configuration parameters. For more information on the set command, run the RACADM command "racadm help set".

Is there something wrong with this command?
Is there an easier way to do that?

Comment: Looks like a warning to me, not an error. I don't know that command though.

Comment: well, when i run this command an re-boot the server. the server doesn't boot from PXE

Comment: "An easier way" - have you tried the web interface if there is one?

Comment: I usually use web interface, but it take long time and i have many servers i need to install them same time.

Answer (score 0):

The problem fixed.

```
racadm config -g cfgServerInfo -o cfgServerBootOnce 1
racadm config -g cfgServerInfo -o cfgServerFirstBootDevice PXE
racadm serveraction powercycle
```

Used these 3 commands